# I can' t access to column that is added afterward by me. What should I do?

Tags: android, database, sqlite

Firstly I created a table :

```
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
     db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + "sorular"
             + " (_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,"
             + "soruIcerik TEXT," + " siklar1 TEXT," + " siklar2 TEXT,"
             + " siklar3 TEXT," + "siklar4 TEXT," + "cevap INTEGER);");
}
```

and after then I added the datas

After then I decided to add a new column to my table and I wrote this code:

```
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        if(newVersion > oldVersion){
          db.execSQL("ALTER TABLE sorular ADD COLUMN zorluk INTEGER");
        }
    }
```

I added datas to new column as manuel

but when I want to access to datas from new column, the application has stopped unexpectedly. The code is like these:

```
 String soruMetin = okunanlar.getString(okunanlar.getColumnIndex("soruIcerik"));//it's normal
 String siklar1 = okunanlar.getString(okunanlar.getColumnIndex("siklar1"));    //it's normal
 String siklar2 = okunanlar.getString(okunanlar.getColumnIndex("siklar2"));    //it's normal
 String siklar3 = okunanlar.getString(okunanlar.getColumnIndex("siklar3"));    //it's normal
 String siklar4 = okunanlar.getString(okunanlar.getColumnIndex("siklar4"));    //it's normal
 int dogruCevap = okunanlar.getInt(okunanlar.getColumnIndex("cevap"));         //it's normal
 int zorluk = okunanlar.getInt(okunanlar.getColumnIndex("zorluk"));            //it has problem
```

What is the problem? How to solve it?

Comment: Fresh installation will not trigger onUpgrade, they will run onCreate, if you have made any changes in onUpgrade, you need to include it in onCreate too, onCreate must always run complete latest structure of your database, which means you should declare sorular field in your create table statement.

Comment: I have done whatever you say but result is the same. Both I have added `ALTER TABLE sorular ADD COLUMN zorluk INTEGER` to onUpgrade and I have done `CREATE TABLE sorular (_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT, soruIcerik TEXT, siklar1 TEXT, siklar2 TEXT, siklar3 TEXT, siklar4 TEXT, cevap INTEGER, zorluk INTEGER)` to onCreate . And they were run in the same time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should change your `onCreate` to this, with the new column added:

```
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
     db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + "sorular"
             + " (_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,"
             + "soruIcerik TEXT," + " siklar1 TEXT," + " siklar2 TEXT,"
             + " siklar3 TEXT," + "siklar4 TEXT," + " zorluk INTEGER" + "cevap INTEGER);");
}
```

Table created from the former sql will be altered in `onUpgrade`

Comment: Uppss! I forgot to add 'zorluk' to my array of columns. I have just recognized it. I'm sorry. I've fixed it. Thanks a lot..